# SQL Server adapter, Rails 4, Tiny Tds 7 or 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby-on-rails-4, sql-server-2012, tiny-tds

I need help with this:

tha same variable `@myDate = DateTime.now`

(or also `DateTime.now.strftime('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'`, or also `DateTime.now.to_time`)

is causing me error in query.

`Error during conversion from varchar to samlldatetime.`

My query is for two different tables:

The first is ok, but Date is not PRIMARY KEY and NULL values are accepted.

The second, where is the error, IS **PRIMARY KEY** and **NULL VALUES ARE NOT ACCEPTED**.

I'm using:

`ruby
gem 'tiny_tds', '~> 0.9.5.rc.3'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'`

or also

`ruby 
gem 'tiny_tds', '~> 0.7.0'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'`

**UPDATE**:

I the variable

`@myDate` is: `DateTime.now` and then `2016-02-29T09:45:01+00:00`

in my first table everything is OK. No problem.

In my second table I have the error.

If I change the big query from this:

`EXEC sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO ... bla bla bla ... SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS bigint) AS Ident', N'@0 smalldatetime,  ... bla bla bla ... ', @0 = '02-29-2016 09:45:01.855', ... bla bla bla ...`

to

`EXEC sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO ... bla bla bla ... SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS bigint) AS Ident', N'@0 smalldatetime,  ... bla bla bla ... ', @0 = '2016-29-02 09:45:01.855', ... bla bla bla ...`

the query is accepted from my sql server!

**How to fix this?**

Comment: UPDATE added to question.

Comment: you may show the declaration of both column definitions. are they different?

Comment: No, it's the same definitio, except for NULL VALUES. The error is on table that doesn't accept NULL values. But in first table the date is always written, also if NULL Values are accepted in that table (the first). Why this? Can I write the date in strftime but if I do in my two queries the @myDate isn't anymore. Crazy!

Comment: maybe, just to make sure, use current_timestamp to generate the values inside the insert. then you know if it's the driver or the values.